# Javascript : Interface and DTO

Tags: javascript, oop

i am looking to simulate interface and DTO in javascript for this problem.
an object dto, an object caller and different implementation for the same Interface IWorker.

caller will recieve a dto for instantiation, will feed it with user inputs, and then call the correct implementation of Iworker (method execute).

I want that in my code i have juste one instance of dto, and one instance of caller, so i will have juste to call caller.CallWorker() everytime the user make another choice

Please tell me if the idea is good or not and any implementation in javascript is welcome

Thanks a lot

**Edit : 
Thanks for help, will take Bergi solution, but i need one more thing**
So my implementation will be like this :

```
var caller = {
    callWorker: function(obj) {
        if(obj.id == 1)  Worker1.execute();
        if(obj.id == 2)  Worker2.execute();
        if(obj.id == 2)  Worker3.execute();
    }
};
```

but this means that i have to add all worker defintions(one js script per implementation) in the html page.
I want to just add dynamically the scripts, in fact active worker depends on a lot of business logic, so i will include them dynamically to have only active workers in the page.
How do you recommend me to do ? Do all conditions in caller.callworker ? **or there is more elegant approach.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> i am looking to simulate interface

There are no "interfaces" in the dynamical typed language JavaScript, as well as there are no classes. The nearest simulation is a function that checks whether a given object has a certain set of methods; yet it cannot make any type or functionality tests.

> and DTO

The nearest thing to a DTO is a JSON-serialisable object. That means it has no cycles, does not contain `Date` objects or even host objects.

> I want that in my code i have juste one instance of dto, and one instance of caller, so i will have juste to call caller.CallWorker() everytime the user make another choice

That's another design pattern: Singletons. They can be easily coded in JS, since objects can be created on the fly and don't need a class and a constructor that needs to prevent multiple instantiation. Just use object literals for them.

> any implementation in javascript is welcome

It's just a simple example, but you can extend it where you need:

```
function makeDTO(id) {
    // creates a basic data structure, with empty or default values or from parameters
    return {
        id: id,
        userInput: [],
        validate: false,
        …
    };
}
var caller = {
    callWorker: function(obj) {
        // do something
    }
};

var dto = makeDTO(14);
caller.callWorker(dto);
var asString = JSON.stringify(dto);
```

> or there is more elegant approach.

Make workers an array or object. For example

```
var workers = {
    1: {/* std worker #1 */},
    …
};
// then the caller will look like this:
var caller = {
    callWorker: function(obj) {
        var workerName = obj.id; // just the id? Or something more complex
        if (workerName in workers)
            workers[workerName].execute(obj);
        else
            dynamicallyLoadWorker(workerName, function callbackWhenLoaded(worker) {
                workers[workerName] = worker;
                worker.execute(obj);
            });
    }
};
```

Comment: I have edited the question, i need one more advise.
Thanks for help.

Comment: i don't need the dynamicallyLoadWorker. i will include all active worker js files in the first load of the page and will generate  array worker server side too 
Thanks for the solution

Comment: Ah, I see you wanted to *pre*-load them dynamically. However, you can see the oppurtunities of using a collection…

Comment: Yes i will pre-load only active workers, perhaps even minifie all js files in one because it"s a public website and i need high performance and speed load

Answer (score 2):

Since JavaScript is dynamically typed, there is no need for the `interface` construct.  You can call your method for each of your implementations without inheriting from an interface.  In terms of DTO, the same answer really applies.  You can use JSON to construct an object however you would like and transfer it over the wire without the need of any of the statically typed constructs you mentioned.

Comment: I have to make some search about dynamically typed languages.
So if i understand you, i can do like this :
function doSomething(obj){
   if obj.id == 1 obj.execute();
   if obj.id == 2 obj.doExecute(); 
};
so no need to implementing an interface, just perhaps for elegant purpose only.

Answer (score 2):

[JS.Class](http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/) allows you to create [interfaces](http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/interfaces.html).

Comment: There is a lot of js frameworks so i don't know where to begin.
Microsoft with typescript, google ...
Which one you think i better to learn? or just JS OOP is enough

Comment: why would you use JS.Class over Typescript? seems a strange recommendation unless there's a reason

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding Interface:**

For javascript there is [JSDoc @interface](https://jsdoc.app/tags-interface.html).

If you prefer Typescript, go for [Interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html).

If you just want some code hints from the IDE of what is defined and what is not defined, I used [JSDoc @typedef](https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef.html#examples) recently:

```js
/**
 * @typedef {Object} MyType
 * @property {boolean} foo
 * @property {function} bar
 * @property {(running|paused)} baz
 */
```